# PHP json_decode displaying blank

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=hello&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content);
echo $json->images[0]->fixedheight->url[0];
?>
```

I've tried everything- even reading it as an array and it doesn't work.

Any help?

So sorry to bother! Thanks again.

Comment: Its non outputting anything.

Comment: do a vardump of $json and see whay you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access it this way

```
echo $json->data[0]->images->fixed_height->url;
```

That is beacause the `$data` is an array , and it has an `object` as its first parameter.

Comment: +1 - You can also suggest him to loop around to get all values not just a first one.

Comment: Thanks Rik , But seems like he needs just the URL .

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 <?php
    $url = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=hello&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC";
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content);
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($json->data[0]->images->fixed_height->url);
    exit;
    ?>
```